# Query Search database for text string

Tags: mysql

I try adapting other question asked here about this matter but seems to complicated to remake. So I'm asking again, how do I search a database for a number, I have 'database' with column id and number and I want to search for number 655985025897377800. This might be simple and my brain bluescreens again.

```
id number
1 655985025897377792
2 655985025897377800
3 655985025897377900
4 655985025897377234
5 655985025897377213
6 655985025897377122
```

Comment: use where number='655985025897377792' or use number like '%655985025897377792%'

Comment: like I said it was simple but my brain blue screened :) SELECT row FROM database WHERE row = ? . Thanks

Comment: `SELECT * FROM database WHERE number LIKE '%655985025897377800%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use where with **=**

```
where number='655985025897377792'
```

Use where with **like**

```
use number like '%655985025897377792%'
```

Comment: I'll accept this as answer but I have to wait 4 more minutes. Cheers and Thanks again